# How to determine if a column is an unsigned integer in Sybase ASE?

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

Unsigned integers were introduced as part of v15.0.  How do we determine if a field is defined as unsigned?

Answer (score 0):

If you examine the contents of the systypes system table you will now see types for the unsigned types, e.g. uint for unsigned integer.  If your field is an unsigned integer, it will be this type, not the int type.  Querying the syscolumns table will confirm this, e.g.

```
select o.name, c.name, t.name from sysobjects o 

inner join syscolumns c on o.id = c.id 

inner join systypes t on c.type = t.type

where o.name = 'table-name' and c.name = 'column_name'
```